# What is the optimal way to fetch graphics card name and info in a Windows C++ app?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, directx, dxgi

I'm trying to pull some information from client machines that I'd like to be formatted almost exactly as it's seen here from "dxdiag.exe":
[image]

I realize there should be an API for this type of functionality, but [I've searched and searched and can't figure out library or header file I need to include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb318763(v=vs.85)) to access this tool. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Vista or later, use [DXGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi).

```
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <wrl/client.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

ComPtr<IDXGIFactory1> dxgiFactory;
HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(dxgiFactory.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
if (FAILED(hr)) // ... error handling

ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
for (UINT adapterIndex = 0;
     SUCCEEDED(dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters1(
               adapterIndex,
               adapter.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
     adapterIndex++)
{
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 desc = {};
    hr = adapter->GetDesc1(&desc);
    if (FAILED(hr)) // ... error handling

    if (desc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE)
    {
        // Don't select the Basic Render Driver adapter.
        continue;
    }

    // desc.VendorId: VID
    // desc.DeviceId: PID
    // desc.Description: name string seen above
}
```

> You can also look at the source code for [DirectX Capabilities Viewer](https://github.com/microsoft/DxCapsViewer) and the sample [SystemInfoUWP](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/System/SystemInfoUWP).

I used [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) as a C++ smart-pointer for COM.

Comment: Thank you sir! I saw your name and icon all over several repos while researching. It's very cool to get an answer from the most qualified person in the world. I'm still a bit new to C++, so I'm not sure if the following is correct or not. I needed to add these lines to get your code to work: 
``` #include <wrl/client.h>```
```#include <dxgi.h>```
```#pragma comment(lib, "DXGI.lib")```
```using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;```

I also had to add the ```namespace DX``` from this file: https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/blob/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP/pch.h